# How do i enable hover effect on an image if the text before it is hovered?

Tags: html, css, sprite

If .text is hovered, how do I also haver .imageis?

```
<a href="#" class="text">All My Clipboards</a>
        <a class="imageis sprite_image_base" href="#"></a>
```

I tried doing something like this in my CSS:

```
.text:hover, .imageis:hover + .text {
    background-position: -107px -311px !important;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 23px;
}
```

Note: I want to do this with pure css without jquery.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why others are taking about Javascript, this is easily done with CSS.

You use the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) or [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

First, declare that you want .text to be hovered for something to happen, like this: `.text:hover`, then add a sibling combinator: `~` or `+`, and finally select the sibling you want to affect, in this case: `.imageis`.

Put it together and you get:

```
.text:hover + .imageis {
    /* css-stuff */
}
```

You could also select both elements' parent and do a regular descendant selector, like this:

```
.parent:hover .imageis {
    /* css-stuff */
}
```

Comment: That first case is going to be pretty fragile, depending on your two anchor elements strictly being adjacent in all cases...  You might want to prioritize the second case (http://jsfiddle.net/5wC2c/).

Comment: As @serhalp says, the second case with a parent in the selector will provide the best browser support and is the least fragile method, with the general sibling combinator being the second least fragile method but also the least supported.

Comment: Can this work in the opposite direction? Say I have text first and image second like in the above case, now when image is hovered can the text change too?

Comment: Sadly, no, there's no CSS selector for previous sibling. It can be done with jQuery, though.